# Django не видит настройки не могу понять почему

Tags: python, django

Что ему надо? Как исправить эту ошибку?
Значит пытаюсь я телеграм-бота на aiogram3 подружить с джангой. Написал команду, которая должна возвращать список курсов

```py
@sync_to_async
def get_courses() -> List[Courses]:
    return Courses.objects.all()
```

Пробую запустить - выдаёт вот такой трейсбек. При этом само по себе джанго-приложение работает `python manage.py runserver` без ошибок и в админку пускает и элементы в таблицы бд вносит

А если просто пишу `print(get_courses())`, то ошибка вот такая

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/garb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils.db_commands import get_courses
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/utils/db_commands.py", line 5, in <module>
    from database_dj.dj_app.models import Users, Courses
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/database_dj/dj_app/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Courses(models.Model):
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in _setup

raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. 
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Погуглил попробовал прописать `settings.configure()` в `models.py` до объявления класса `Courses`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()

class Courses(models.Model):
    class Meta:
```

Получил другую ошибку, которую тоже не понял, как решить..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/garb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils.db_commands import get_courses    
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/utils/db_commands.py", line 5, in <module>
    from database_dj.dj_app.models import Users, Courses    
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/database_dj/dj_app/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Courses(models.Model):    
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()    
File "/home/i/MyPros/F/sarafanka_bot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

НО

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     ЗДЕСЬ-ТО ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ ПРИСУТСТВУЕТ (пробовал его в разных формах прописывать, 
от просто dj_app до вот такого полного пути к классу
    'database_dj.dj_app.apps.DjAppConfig',
]
```

Comment: Что такое «просто пишу»? Пишете где когда зачем?